# React component interop

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react and am working through the tutorials. I think I have a grasp on the [Multiple Components](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html) parent-child explanation, but am struggling to figure out how to provide interop (in state, events, etc) **between** independent components. So, given the following indepent, stateful components (that have child components, etc):

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <FooBox />,
  document.getElementById('foo')
);
```

and

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <BarBox />,
  document.getElementById('bar')
);
```

Is there a way to interop between `FooBox` and `Barbox`, or do I need to nest both under `ReactDOM.render`? And if I do, will that still "work"?

Use case: `onClick` of one of `Foo`'s children, I want to display `BarBox` (with stateful information from `FooBars` children.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should render into a single element so that you have a "single entry point" for the application and its corresponding React DOM. Some parent component can then control whether `BarBox` is displayed by setting a boolean on its local `state`.

For example, you could pass an `onClick` handler via `props` to `FooBox`:

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  displayBarBox () {
    this.setState({ displayBarBox: true })
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <FooBox onClick={this.displayBarBox.bind(this)} />
        {this.state.displayBarBox &&
          <BarBox />}
      </div>
    )
  } 
}
```

And then use this click handler in `FooBox`:

```
class FooBox extends React.Component {
  render () {
    // Use the click handler passed via props
    // (simple example)
    return <div onClick={this.props.onClick} />
  }
}

FooBox.propTypes = {
  onClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Like angular, does React have the same paradigm (i.e. nest your **app**, not their components?)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the difference? It is rare that you will need multiple entry points (`ng-app` / `ReactDOM.render`) when using either framework.

Comment: Thanks again - sorry, I don't have much UI experience, more a backend guy. But your examples pointed out a few other features I need to get my head around.

Comment: My first comment was meant to address the single-entry point model you described in your answer, sorry if that didn't come across clear enough